# The var i goes over the array length

Tags: javascript

I came across the following interview question:

```
var arr = [ 10, 12, 15, 21 ];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  //console.log('outside timeout ' + i)
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('Index: ' + i + ', element: ' + arr[i])
  }, 3000)
}
```

by the time setTimeout runs the loop has finished running. But, how does i inside the setTimeout outputs 4? Shouldn't it stop at 3?

https://codepen.io/AlexanderWeb00/pen/vjXmBo

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958556/why-does-settimeout-behave-incorrectly-inside-a-for-loop. It is only touching a `closure`. @Satpal

Comment: @Alex I I had given answer first...

Comment: at the end, the value of the variable is always greater than the last value to be true in the check, because this works as exit condition after the last increment. it has nothing to do with the timeout. the timeout uses the last value, because oof the value at the time where the timeout is calling the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `setTimeout` around an IIFE

```js
var arr = [ 10, 12, 15, 21 ];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  //console.log('outside timeout ' + i)
  (function(i){
        setTimeout(function(){
           console.log('Index: ' + i + ', element: ' + arr[i])
        }, 3000)
    })(i);
}
```

**Reasoning** - `var` are functional scope variables and even if specified in a `if/for/while` will be available in the whole function. The condition governs the number of times the loop will run, which over here breaks when i becomes 4. However, when the timeout function is executed for the `i=0` or `i=1` and others, i has already reached 4 as it has completed the for loop. Hence, you need to explicitly pass the value of i using an IIFE.

Also, if you are using ES6 and above, you can use `let` also specified by Satpal in comments.

```js
var arr = [ 10, 12, 15, 21 ];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  //console.log('outside timeout ' + i)
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('Index: ' + i + ', element: ' + arr[i])
  }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: That's great, but what's causing i to be 4?

Comment: @Alex or, use `let` instead of `var` i.e. `for(let i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {`

Comment: what about "i < arr.length"?

Comment: The `final expression i++` is run after the `loop body`. In time it gets there `i==4` already. Then `i<arr.length` stops it.

Comment: array length is 4 so loop will  run 4 times for index 0 to 3 as 3 < 4. It is as simple as that

Comment: @Alex - I have added reasoning and alternates. Hope it helps and clarifies.

Comment: @nikhilagw it does indeed. Thank you

Comment: @Alex - Good to hear that :)